# In Rest API while reutrn datetime null create a error in json format

Tags: c#, api, rest, json.net

I have create one get method in  Rest server which will return the data in json format.
In the json object contain one datetime field ,If i am passing this datetime field null then it will through an exception.

This is the code I have that doesn't seem to work

```
public class meta 
{ 
  private System.DateTime createdField; 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaFo‌​rm.Unqualified)] 
     public System.DateTime created { 
       get { return this.createdField; } 
       set { this.createdField = value; } 
     } 
  }
```

Comment: Add more details e.g. your sample code, the exception, etc

Comment: You have to make this field `Nullable`, to accept `null`'s

Answer (score 2):

Make that `DateTime` `Nullable` and it should work.

Also you can try putting `[JsonIgnore]` on that property.

Example

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mo = new MyObject { integerValue = null, dateTimeValue = null };
            var ser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mo);
            var deser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ser, typeof(MyObject));
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public int? integerValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateTimeValue { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for prompt Reply.but can you suggest me how can i set the below object property null . public class meta {
    
    private System.DateTime createdField;
 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public System.DateTime created {
        get {
            return this.createdField;
        }
        set {
            this.createdField = value;
        }
    }
}

Comment: class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mo = new MyObject { integerValue = null, dateTimeValue = null };
            var ser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mo);
            var deser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ser, typeof(MyObject));
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public int? integerValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateTimeValue { get; set; }        
    }

Comment: @user1217665, you should add these details to your question to improve it, and other users can help you as well.

Comment: I have to agree, its tough understanding what you want to do if you didnt show us code from the first post :)

Comment: you are welcome, please lets try to make questions with examples :)